# Accessing Email logs using REST or SOQL

Tags: soql, rest-api, email

For Email Logs, we follow below steps generally:
Go to Setup--> Logs --> Email Log Files --> Request an Email Logs --> Download(once it is ready).

Is there any way to access this information programatically using REST API or using SOQL. 
In which object, these information is stored?

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR - Doesn't seem to be available.

So the object in question here is `LogSearchResult`. I found this `SObjectType` by looking at the link to one of these logs. It looked like:

> https://instance.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0BR000000000000

So then I plugged that in to my time tested strategy:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('0BR000000000000').getSObjectType()); // yields LogSearchResult
```

However, when I tried to debug the fields and child relationships of this object, I got bupkus.

```
SObjectType logType = Id.valueOf('0BR000000000000').getSObjectType();

for (SObjectField field : logType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
    system.debug(field); // nada

for (ChildRelationship relation : logType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships())
    system.debug(relation); // nada
```

I also tried querying for it in the `Developer Console` with and without the `Tooling API`, and got the error:

> sObject type 'LogSearchResult' is not supported.

[image: LogSearchResult Query Error]

Also, this object seems to be missing from the listed [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).

Comment: I'm wondering if there has been any improvement in this process.  We need to monitor our Permanent Failure Rate regularly.  I don't want to have to download the email logs every week and analyze our failure rate forever.  Is there any way to automate retrieving email logs on a scheduled basis?  Willing to use SOQL, REST, or whatever approach works.