# create email log request programatically

Tags: email

For Email Logs, we follow below steps generally: Go to Setup--> Logs --> Email Log Files --> Request an Email Logs, is there any way to create the email log request programatically using Rest API or SOQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Email logs using REST or SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140626/accessing-email-logs-using-rest-or-soql)

Comment: [Accessing Email logs using REST or SOQL ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140626/accessing-email-logs-using-rest-or-soql)   cannot answer the question

Comment: What's it missing? It seems pretty clear you cannot do this programatically which is your question.

Comment: There's no API for generating a request. You can easily build your own API by using Selenium or a similar product.